# How to Build Query Table from two OLE DB tables using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, sql, query, table

When I run the following code to create a subset of a table, the error says "An invalid SQL statement was used" [Query]. The error shows in line 39. Is there any idea you can figure this out?

```
import arcpy
# MakeQueryTableOLEDB.py
# Description: Create a query table from two OLE DB tables using a limited set of
# fields and establishing an equal join.

try:
    # Local variables...
    tableList = ["Database Connections/OLE DB Connection.odc/ORADBA.DLY_AVG_DATA"]

    fieldList = [["ORADBA.DLY_AVG_DATA.OBJECTID", 'OBJECTID'],["ORADBA.DLY_AVG_DATA.STATION_ID", 'STATION_ID'],\
                ["ORADBA.DLY_AVG_DATA.SENSOR_NUM", 'SENSOR_NUM'],["ORADBA.DLY_AVG_DATA.DMONTH", 'DMONTH'],\
                [ "ORADBA.DLY_AVG_DATA.DDAY", 'DDAY'], ["ORADBA.DLY_AVG_DATA.NO_OF_VALUES", 'NO_OF_VALUES'],\
                ["ORADBA.DLY_AVG_DATA.DLY_AVG", 'DLY_AVG']]
    whereClause = "ORADBA.DLY_AVG_DATA.STATION_ID = 'ADM'"
    keyField = "ORADBA.DLY_AVG_DATA.OBJECTID"
    lyrName = "Query"
    #QueryTable = "C:/RG/Projects/CriticalDataNetwork/QueryTableTest.dbf"
    # Make Query Table...
    arcpy.MakeQueryTable_management(tableList,  lyrName, "USE_KEY_FIELDS", keyField, fieldList, whereClause)

    # Print the total rows
    print arcpy.GetCount_management(lyrName)

    # Print the fields
    Fields = arcpy.ListFields(lyrName)
    for field in Fields:
        print Field.name


    # Save as a dBASE file
    arcpy.CopyRows_management(lyrName, "C:/RG/Projects/CriticalDataNetwork/QueryTest.dbf")

except Exception, e:
    # If an error occurred, print line number and error message
    import traceback, sys
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    print "Line %i" % tb.tb_lineno
    print e.message
```

Comment: Please remove the try/except statements from any code snippet that you present here because they can mask the error messages that would otherwise be helpful.